# What is the default max ammo for a scout rifle in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

My Destiny character (a Human Titan) has picked up some armor that allows you to carry extra Scout Rifle ammo. Without any additions, what is the maximum Scout Rifle ammo I can carry? Does it vary by race or class? Is there a chart online that shows per weapon?

I am also unclear if this bonus means a larger magazine (more rounds before reloading, 14 for me) or a larger capacity (more rounds I can pick up, no limit I can see, around 350 is my high water mark).

By comparison, my Sniper Rifle holds 3 rounds in the magazine, but only 16 total. I can walk over stacks of green glowing boxes, but I am constantly told my Special Weapon Ammo is full. Now, if I can get THAT as a bonus, it would be of much greater value to me.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of ammo a gun can carry isn't the same for all guns in the same class - it varies by the weapon. Typically, if a weapon has a lower impact (i.e. does less damage), it will have a larger magazine and hold more ammo in reserver than a weapon with a higher impact.

You can use the [Armory](https://www.bungie.net/en/Armory) on Bungie's website to see all of the items available in the game (and some that aren't available as of this writing). For example, here are all of the [scout rifles in The Taken King](https://www.bungie.net/en/Armory/category?order=3&dir=2&categories=1%2C2%2C8&source=460228854). The site doesn't show how much ammo is in reserver for each weapon, but it does show the magazine size (in general, the larger the magazine size the more ammo you can hold for that weapon).

Comment: So, dumb question: When the armor says "carry extra Scout Rifle ammo", does that increase magazine size, or total amount you can carry?

Comment: That link shows the magazine size, but not the total amount you can carry.

Comment: Armor bonuses increase the total amount you can carry. And I realize that link shows magazine size and not how much you can carry, but in general the larger the magazine size the more ammo you carry for the weapon.

Comment: @CigarDoug To answer the update to your question, there are bonuses for most all weapon types to carry more ammo (include sniper rifles) except for swords.